# How to define the body of a method in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am actaully embarrassed to ask this question as I don't remember how it is done. I am trying to define a method that I can change its body whenever I need. It will be used for a floating action button that will have a certain function in each page of a `PageView()`. I didn't find anything about it, so can someone remind me of what and how this is done?